# How to add new html items with Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am making a flask app that creates an "Order of Services" for a church. This basically just allows you to input a list of items that can be seen by all the staff in real-time. Is there any way to append an html item? To clarify, here is my python:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, url_for, redirect, session, render_template, g
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Thisisasecret!'

def connect_db():
    connect = sqlite3.connect('Path to my DataBase')
    connect.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return connect

def get_db():
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite3'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
    return g.sqlite_db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db.close()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')
    else:
        serviceitem = request.form['serviceitem']

        db = get_db()
        db.execute('insert into oos (serviceitem) values (?)', [serviceitem])
        db.commit()

    return render_template('index.html', serviceitem=serviceitem)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My `index.html` is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SFBC Order of Services</title>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet"
                href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Raleway;
            }

            div {
                margin-left: 500px;
            }

            span {
                margin-left: 520px;
            }

            h1, h2, h3, h4 {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        {% block content %}
        <h1>Santa Fe Baptist Church Order of Services</h1>
        <h3>Please select an item or create a new one below.</h3>
        <br><br><br>

        <div>Add a new Service item: 
            <form action="/add" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="serviceitem">
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </div><br>

        <h1>You appended {{ serviceitem }} to the Database.</h1>

        {% endblock %}

    </body>
</html>
```

So what I want to do is to add a new list item once a new item is added, and maybe remove a placeholder once there is a value. I know that I can do this with javascript, so if there is any way to trigger some javascript that would be great, too!
Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

I tried @the_gañañufla 's answer, but it did not *quite* work. When I append a number to the database, it returns this:

[image: Isn't it annoying when pictures disappear? Even though I don't know you I relish the thought of your annoyance :)]

If I edit it to include the `serviceitem` instead of `item`, then it just puts in "letters" or whatever I put in, iterating it the amount of times that there are letters. (7 letters in letters, so it shows seven letters).

Sorry if that is convoluted and unreadable for my bad word choice :)

Comment: Try now, this iterate over a string, but transform serviceitem to a list, i edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

In the route('/') you need to add a query.all(), to get all the information of your db, and send this data in the render template.

```
 @app.route('/')
 def index():
     db = get_db()
     serviceitem = db.query.all()
     return render_template('index.html', serviceitem=serviceitem)
```

In other case, in unnecesary to send info with the render in the /add action

```
 @app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
    def add():
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template('index.html')
        else:
            serviceitem = request.form['serviceitem']

            db = get_db()
            db.execute('insert into oos (serviceitem) values (?)'[serviceitem])
            db.commit()

        return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: so this (second answer) is just what I had before. What it is doing is showing me ONE value, the latest value, but not any other, older ones. To be perfectly clear, I want it to show all of the appended items.

Comment: Ok, now i understand your question, you need to make a query.all() in index()

Comment: Hmmm.... This seems like it would work, but it appears that it does need the info with the render of /add, and it still only shows one option. I might have a solution, I will post it here if it works.

Comment: Ok, but its unnecesary send the info on the render, because you want all the info of the db, not only the data of the form, the only way to construct this is with a query_all().